# does kubernetes pv recognize namespace when created/queried with kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes

I am using GKE with kubectl installed from gcloud components.
I have created a pv (gcePersistentDisk) with namespace scope using kubectl.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: cstor-cs-a-disk-david
  namespace: ns-david
spec:
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: cstor-cs-a-disk-david
    fsType: ext4
    partition: 0
    readOnly: false
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  capacity:
    storage: 200Gi
```

This says that specifying namespace with create pv is/was valid:
http://kubernetes.io/third_party/swagger-ui/#!/api%2Fv1/createNamespacedPersistentVolume

When I run 'kubectl get pv' I see the pv.

```
$ kubectl get pv
NAME                    LABELS    CAPACITY       ACCESSMODES   STATUS      CLAIM     REASON
cstor-cs-a-disk-david   <none>    214748364800   RWO           Available
```

I did not expect this because the pv wasn't created with the default namespace scope.

The same happens if I specify a namespace argument (valid or not).

```
$ kubectl get namespaces
NAME          LABELS    STATUS
default       <none>    Active
kube-system   <none>    Active
ns-david      <none>    Active

$ kubectl get pv --namespace=demo
NAME                    LABELS    CAPACITY       ACCESSMODES   STATUS      CLAIM     REASON
cstor-cs-a-disk-david   <none>    214748364800   RWO           Available
```

If I create a claim against this pv and query it with 'kubectl get pvc' then the claim is not found but is found when I specify the correct namespace.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: cstor-cs-a-disk-claim-david
  namespace: ns-david
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Gi
  volumeName: cstor-cs-a-disk-david

$ kubectl get pvc
NAME      LABELS    STATUS    VOLUME

$ kubectl get pvc --namespace=ns-david
NAME                          LABELS    STATUS    VOLUME
cstor-cs-a-disk-claim-david   map[]     Bound     cstor-cs-a-disk-david
```

Do pv have namespace scope or are they global?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

PVs, like nodes, are not scoped to any namespace. However, as you [noted](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/#not-all-objects-are-in-a-namespace) PVCs, are.

Answer (score 1):

Above solution has link to kube docs to see the list.
but providing commands here directly (in case to check quickly instead of going through doc)

**To see which Kubernetes resources are and aren't in a namespace:**

```
# In a namespace
kubectl api-resources --namespaced=true

# Not in a namespace
kubectl api-resources --namespaced=false
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

pv and namespaces belong to Cluster, so they are not NameSpaced.
pvc is NameSpaced

Answer (score 0):

A quick verification of the PV vs. PVC namespacing using `kubectl` (kudos go to @venkatesha-k):

```
$ kubectl api-resources | grep "pv\|NAMESPACED"
NAME                              SHORTNAMES         APIVERSION                             NAMESPACED   KIND
persistentvolumeclaims            pvc                v1                                     true         PersistentVolumeClaim
persistentvolumes                 pv                 v1                                     false        PersistentVolume
```